# Scala: decode Any[] array using circe.io

Tags: java, json, scala, decoding

I have a Java server creating a message looking like this:

```
@SerializedName("message")
private String _message;

@SerializedName("args")
private Object[] _args;
```

Now in my Scala.js application, I want to deserialize this message using something like:

```
case class Notification(message: String, args: String*)

implicit val messageDecoder: Decoder[Notification] = (c: HCursor) => {
  for {
    message  <- c.downField("message").as[String]
    args     <- c.downField("args").as[List[java.lang.Object]].map(_.toString)
  } yield {
    Notification(level, message, args)
  }
}
```

However, Scala refuses to decode this with the error:

```
implicit error;
[error] !I d: Decoder[List[Object]]
[error] Decoder.importedDecoder invalid because
[error] !I exported: Exported[Decoder[List[Object]]]
[error] Decoder.decodeCanBuildFrom invalid because
[error] !I d: Decoder[Object]
[error] ??Decoder.importedDecoder invalid because
[error]   !I exported: Exported[Decoder[Object]]
[error]
[error] Decoder.decodeList invalid because
[error] !I evidence$2: Decoder[Object]
[error] ??Decoder.importedDecoder invalid because
[error]   !I exported: Exported[Decoder[Object]]
[error]       args       <- 
        c.downField("args").as[List[Object]].map(_.toString)
[error]                                           ^
[error] one error found
```

Any ideas on how to decode this? I only need to call `map(toString)` on the result.

***Edit***

When trying to do something like this:

```
args <- c.downField("args").as[Array[Any]].map(_.toString)
```

I get the following error:

```
diverging implicit expansion for type io.circe.Decoder[A]
[error] starting with value decodeString in object Decoder
[error]       args       <- 
     c.downField("args").as[Array[Any]].map(_.toString)
[error]                                           ^
[error] one error found
```

***Edit 2***

```
args <- c.downField("args").as[Seq[String]].map(_.toString)
```

Does compile, but does not succefully parse the json (Left).

***Edit 3***

One example of the json that is sent (in this case with integers):

```
{
  "message" : "{0} is smaller than {1}.",
  "args" : [
    1,
    2
  ]
}
```

The java server could also generate a JSON looking like this:

```
{
  "message" : "{0} is smaller than {1}. ({2})",
  "args" : [
    1,
    2,
    "Hello World!"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Having `Any` is generally a symptom of bad design, and is not to be supported by typeclass (such as codec)

Comment: Well this whole concept kind of mimics Java's `public static String format(String format, Object... args)`.

Comment: Curios, can you post a sample of the json input ?

Comment: @Biswanath I added an example.

Comment: What kind of types do you expect for args, like Int, string ? Anything else do you expect ?

Comment: Primitives and strings I'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding it as another answer, so as to keep the history clean.

Basically the following code simply works with the current json value and uses it string representation.

```
case class Notification(message: String, args: String*)

object Notification {

  implicit val anyDecoder : Decoder[Any] =  Decoder.instance(c => {
      c.focus match {
          case Some(x) => Right(x)
          case None => Left(DecodingFailure("Could not parse", List()))
      }
  })

  implicit val messageDecoder: Decoder[Notification] = Decoder.instance(c => {
    for {
      message <- c.downField("message").as[String]
      args <- c.downField("args").as[List[Any]].map(_.toString)
    } yield {
      Notification(message, args)
    }
  })

}
```

And the test case is

```
val json = """
            {
                "message" : "Hello" ,
                "args"    : [ 2, 3.234, 4,"good", true  ]
            }
            """

println(decode[Notification](json))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your args consists of Int and String, see if this works for you

```
case class Notification(message: String, args: String*)

object Notification {


  implicit val decodeIntOrString: Decoder[Either[Int, String]] =
    Decoder[Int].map(Left(_)).or(Decoder[String].map(Right(_)))

  implicit val messageDecoder: Decoder[Notification] = Decoder.instance(c => {
    for {
      message <- c.downField("message").as[String]
      args <- c.downField("args").as[List[Either[Int,String]]].map(_.toString)
    } yield {
      Notification(message, args)
    }
  })

}
```

This was the test case

```
 val json = """
            {
                "message" : "Hello" ,
                "args"    : [ 2, 3, 4,"good"  ]
            }
            """

 println(decode[Notification](json))
```

Also I will like to point out to the circe discussion https://github.com/circe/circe/issues/216, which talks about the issue more or less same. I think the idiomatic circe decision seems to be the types will derive deserialisation.

Comment: I guess this would work for Ints and Strings, but I'd have to do more of those Either decoding functions for floats, bools, etc. which would get very ugly. (sth like: `decodeIntOrStringOrBoolOrFloat: Decoder[Either[Int, Either[String, Either[Boolean, Float]]]]`